# bringing eth0 up without cable

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox, ethernet

I need to enable my eth0 network which is configured with a static IP with the network manager. I have also multiple VM's and all that in one machine. I need to test one Server VM which is also configured with a static IP.

Now I want to connect to this VM's with the host machine. But the host machine don't enables the eth0 because there is no cable plugged in. Furthermore I don't have the possibility to use a cable or any kind of physical network, because it will be a live demo.

The VM's are Virtualbox Machines which are "connected" with as a network bridge on eth0.

Comment: Wow i never thought to get a downvote without a comment.

Comment: do you host machine needs to access the VM's?

Comment: yep the host machine need to access the VM's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your host machine has wifi feature built in, you can use the bridged network mode :

1. Turn on wifi hotspot feature on your smartphone
2. Connect host machine to your smartphone's hotspot network
3. In the VM's settings, use bridged network and choose the host's wireless adapter as the source

And done.